# Add selector to object already stored in variable

Tags: jquery, variables, object, syntax

I'm new to jQuery, apologies if my vocabulary is wrong, please correct me so I can learn the right way.

I'm attempting to use best practices for optimized performance. I've been told to store static objects in a variable when possible. I'm trying to store the parent object #mytable, then navigate down into child objects from there.

```
var count=1;
$('#eachselector').each(function(){

  var MyTable = $('#mytable'+count);
  $(MyTable+' td[condition=true][condition2=true]').attr('do', 'stuff');
  $(MyTable+' table[condition=true][condition2=true]').attr('do', 'stuff');

  count++;
});
```

This gives me the error "uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]".

I suspect that I'm treating MyTable as a string when called inside of the each() but not sure what the syntax should look like.

Thanks!

Comment: You concatenate a string to a jQuery object (myTable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
var MyTable = $('#mytable'+count);
MyTable.find('td[condition=true][condition2=true]').attr('do', 'stuff');
MyTable.find('table[condition=true][condition2=true]').attr('do', 'stuff');
```

This uses jQuery's [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function to search the descendants of `$('#mytable'+count)`. The reason your code isn't working is that `MyTable` is a jQuery object not a string.

You could also use `$('selector', MyTable)` but internally it just maps to the `.find()` function.

Comment: This is great Joe, tested and works perfectly. However, for the sake of learning, is it not possible to concatenate additional selectors directly to the variable like I tried to do?

I assume this is because I was treating it like a string and not an object. Is that correct?

Comment: @Joe - no problem. It isn't possible as `myTable` is an object but you're trying to concatenate it like it was a string. For example, this would work: `$('#mytable'+count+' td[condition=true][condition2=true]')` as you're just concatenating strings. However, this way of doing it messier and less optimised. To take a look at `MyTable` in more detail use `console.log(MyTable);` after you define it then use your browser's developer tools to view it.

Comment: Excellent. In fact, `$('#mytable'+count+' td[condition=true][condition2=true]')` was my original draft of this code, then I wanted to go back and implement a better way.

Thanks so much Joe very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
  $('td[condition=true][condition2=true]', MyTable).attr('do', 'stuff');
```

This says set 'do' attribute of all td with condition1 and condition2 as true to value 'stuff'